# Angular 7 get corrupted file while downloading blob

Tags: angular, typescript, download, httpclient, filesaver.js

Using Angular 7, i am calling api by posting the url file and try to download it by using 'saveAs' function from the fileSaver library. 
The file is downloading but **it cannot be opened because it's corrupted**.

my call is the following:

```
var file_url = (response as any).headers['Location'] + 'files/Data.xlsx';
var filename = 'Data_' + this.getDateService.getDateFile() + '.xlsx';

const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          }),
          responseType: 'arraybuffer',
          observe: 'response'
        };

let downloadParameters = { filename: 'Data_' + this.getDateService.getDateFile() + '.xlsx', file: file_url }

this.downloadFileService.downloadFile(downloadParameters, httpOptions).subscribe(reponse => {

          var blob = new Blob([(response as any).body], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformat-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
          saveAs(blob, filename);
})
```

**What i tried**:

- switch the Type MIME **application/vnd.openxmlformat-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet** by **application/octet-stream**
- switch the responseType **arraybuffer** by **blob** or **blob as json**

**Below, the response headers from the service**:

[image]

**The file is present in the response body**:

[image]

Do you guys have any clues ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
this.downloadFileService.downloadFile(downloadParameters, { responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe(blob=> {
  saveAs(blob, filename);
})
```

Comment: Wow, thanks you, it actually is working. Why it's actually working without the httpHeaders ?

Comment: Here `{ responseType: 'blob' }` this is the http header. I didn't store in in another variable. It would be great if you upvote the answer too :)

Comment: I wrote "response" instead of "reponse". it's working by correcting this.